# HQL How to query Table with List of Objects as a set of conditions?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a class called form

```
Class Form {
    String id;
    String version;
    String minVersion;  
}
```

Now I have a `List<Form>` with me.
I have to query a table which satisfies the condition such that the id, version, type all as a set satisfies ie. I want to find all the {id, version, minVersion} which is the exact same in the table from my list. For example

I have a table like this

```
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| id | version | minVersion | passage |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
|  1 |       2 |          2 | Hi      |
|  1 |       3 |          1 | Hello   |
|  2 |       2 |          2 | Hi      |
|  3 |       3 |          3 | Hi      |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
```

I want to select 2 rows from it given as a List: {id: 1, version: 3, minVersion: 1} and {id: 2, version: 2, minVersion: 2}

I wrote a query like this,

```
SELECT id, version, type, passage FROM Content WHERE (id, version, type) IN (:id, :version, :minVersion);
```

But how do to convert into HSQL and setParameter for it?

Comment: Do you use spring jpa?

Comment: yes will it help here? the HSQL command gives me an exception @SternK

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion if your table size is small get all the elements specific to ids and filter in java layer**

Please use the IN syntax in your query and setParameterList API.

For Example:

String hql = " SELECT id, version, type, passage FROM Content WHERE id in (:ids) "

And while forming query use

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("ids", idList);
```

[Refer this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.hibernate.Query&method=setParameterList)

Comment: The id will not be unique. Combination of id, version, minVersion will be unique. I want to query a list of set of values {id, verion, minVersion}

Comment: ok you have edited your question  now can you try this logic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654259/how-to-do-a-select-with-a-composite-key

Comment: @ChandramowliJ You can do this if your table size is small get all the elements and filter in java layer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Form> findByIdInAndVersionInAndMinVersionIn(List<String> ids, List<String> versions, List<String> minVersions);
```